# "add a couple of pages" to the existing Angular application, with a totally different look (different style, no header/footers etc.)

Tags: angular

We have an Angular 7 webapp that I need to alter and I have no good idea how (no experience with Angular whatsoever, not much with the front-end as well; none in the team as well).

All pages of the app have the same style (header, footer, css). This is defined in the root component of the web app, "AppComponent". 
What I need to do is to create "a couple of pages" that would have a totally different look (no headers, different css) but would use the same services (same code) for some internal logic (validation e.g.) + talking to the server. The entry point will be a direct link.

Ideally, I would like to change the code of the existing application as little as possible: these new pages are kind of like an experiment (still, should go into the prod codebase).

How can I do that?

To me it looks like there is 1 entry point — main.ts — which loads 1 module — let's call it "AppModule" — which has 1 bootstrap component — "AppComponent". If that is true, I tought I could then:

1. either do the "branching" inside AppComponent

   - not ideal since I would like to touch it as little as possible
   - also, not sure how to have most pages still as ("AppComponent" + routing inside) and then a couple of pages as ("ExperimentalComponent" + routing inside)
2. or create a whole different application that would be packaged into its own folder

   - but how can I then reuse the code of the services? would be ideal to not have imports across "modules", like "../../../mainmodule/src/app/services/my.service.ts"
   - also, looks like a bit too much hassle for this simple "a couple of pages"

Is there a good and "right" way to do it?

Sorry if what I write does not make much sense or is outrageously lame, I am struggling to make sense of Angular for myself so far :) I have started skimming through a book since googling on a per-question basis did not help too much, but maybe you can give me some hints that will speed me up with this.
Thank you!

---

Just to give a couple of details, though maybe it's all super-conventional or irrelevant.

Schematically, AppComponent (`app.component.html`):

```
<mat-sidenav-container... // <--- I need to get rid of this

    ... HEADER DEFINED HERE, 300 LoC ... // <--- and this

    <!-- Main container -->
    <div class="container-fluid main-container">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>

</mat-sidenav-container>

<div class="copyright">&copy; {{companyName}}, {{currentYear}}</div> // <--- and this
```

AppModule (`app.module.ts`):

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent, LoginPageComponent, ...],
    imports: [AppRoutingModule, ...],
    providers: [AuthGuard, AuthService, ErrorService, ServerStatusService, UserService, ... ], // <--- I need to use these in my new "pages"
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

AppRoutingModule (`app-routing.module.ts`):

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { LoginPageComponent } from './components/login/login-page.component';
import { AuthGuard, ... } from './services/guard.service';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'user-login', component: LoginPageComponent },
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'home', canActivate: [AuthGuard], component: HomePageComponent },
    ...
    {
        path: '**',
        component: NotFoundPageComponent
    }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

`main.ts`:

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: I would just define classes in app.component.scss then inject the route service in app.component.ts and dynamically pick defined class for your header depending on what route.url you are on. Can I take a look at app.component.scss and app.component.ts files

Answer (score 1):

**Total working** demo you can find here in this.. [StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rg62j3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

**Very first** basic solution is to use service and service maintains state of what to display or not.

**Your service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
    export class CustomstyleService {
        isLogin : boolean = true;
        constructor() { }
    }
```

Above Service is singleton service and then you can inject in every component where you need some custom implementation of component. If you want to hide all element when user press Login-page then we can use `*ngIf` directive to remove and add other parts of page.

**app.component.html**

```
<app-header *ngIf="!customStyle.isLogin"></app-header>
<app-login *ngIf="customStyle.isLogin" ></app-login>
<app-container *ngIf="!customStyle.isLogin"></app-container>
<app-footer class="footer" *ngIf="!customStyle.isLogin"></app-footer>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  constructor(private customStyle: CustomstyleService){}
}
```

Above, we inject `CustomstyleService` into component constructor and then we can use `isLogin` property of service into template by using `*ngIf` directive.

**Login.component.ts**

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private customStyle: CustomstyleService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
  signIn(){
    this.customStyle.isLogin = false;
  }
}
```

By pressing SignIn button we changed `isLogin` value to false so then we can show other components of page than login.

This is very basic implementation, You can further enhance this approach by doing Declarative way using `rxjs` way of using `BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true)`.